# C# WinForms DataGridView ComboBox databinding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I believe I have read every document on the internet regarding this issue and I'm still having trouble.
I have a DataGridView populated by two List and combined into a var

```
topList = ShippingOrder.GetTopGroups();
topItemsList = ShippingOrder.GetCurrentTopSheet();
topList.AddRange(topItemsList);

var newList = topList.OrderBy(x => x.GroupOrder).ToList();
```

One of the columns in the DdataGridView is a ComboBox.  It's populated from a separate List

```
alertList = GetComboBoxValue();
```

It's values are associated with the datagridview combox.

```
emailRecipientDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource = alertList;
emailRecipientDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "EmailAlert";
emailRecipientDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DisplayMember = "PopUpText";
emailRecipientDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.ValueMember = "PopUpValue";
```

The DataPropertyName corresponds to topList.EmailAlert.

The DisplayMember corresponds to alertList.PopUpText.

The ValueMember corresponds to alertList.PopUpValue.

Then the datagrid is filled

```
dgvTopSheet.DataSource = newList;
CurrencyManager cm = (CurrencyManager)(dgvTopSheet.BindingContext[newList]);
cm.Refresh();
```

Once the datagrid is filled, everything looks good except the combobox value is not showing.  I can use the dropdown arrow and the values acquired from the alertList show up but the comboxbox value isn't binding the value from topList on load.

As I understand from the 50 plus documents I've read on the datagridviewcombobox the DataPropertName is the field needed to bind the control to the data in the dgv.  This doesn't appear to be working and 4 hours later I'm a bit frustrated.  Something simple seems to be alluding me greatly.

Any help is appreciated.

eta -

The BusinessObjects Class

```
public class BusinessObjects : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public BusinessObjects()
    {

    }
    private string popUpText;
    public string PopUpText
    {
        get { return popUpText; }
        set
        {
            popUpText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PopUpText"));
        }
    }

    private string popUpValue;
    public string PopUpValue
    {
        get { return popUpValue; }
        set
        {
            popUpValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PopUpValue"));
        }
    }
}
```

The ShippingOrder Class

```
public class ShippingOrder : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private string emailAlert;
    public string EmailAlert
    {
        get { return emailAlert; }
        set
        {
            emailAlert = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("EmailAlert"));
        }
    }

    private string partNumber;
    public string PartNumber
    {
        get { return partNumber; }
        set
        {
            partNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PartNumber"));
        }
    }


}
```

sample data looks like:

ShippingOrder.PartNumber = "1234Dp01".

ShippingOrder.EmailAlert = "BSmith@example.com".

BusinessObject.PopUpText = "Bob Smith".

BusinessObject.PopUpValue = "BSmith@example.com".

Comment: What is "PopUpValue"? `ValueMember` of the combo box `DataSource` should correspond to the `DataPropertyName` of the data grid view `DataSource`.

Comment: Both PopUpValue and PopUpText are fields in a sql table.  The table holds generic values that populate comboboxes throughout the application.  The List<BusinessObjects> alertList retireves these values.
PopUpText = "Bob", "Fred", "Sue"
PopUpValue = "bob@here.com", "fred@here.com", "sue@here.com"

They are also fields in the BusinessObjects class.

Comment: The question was what is the **type** of the `BusinessObject.PopUpValue`, what actually it holds and is it matching the `EmailAlert` property of the grid data. Can't you just post a sample classes and data to reproduce the issue - in other words - [mcve]

Comment: Updated question with Class addition.

Comment: Ivan, your statement got me to recheck my code.  Indeed as you posted ValueMember of the combobox datasource must correspond to the datapropertyname of the datagridview - it did not -  I was naming the datapropertyname after the sql field and not the class name.  Since it was in quotation marks, it didn't present an error.  Your explanation is much appreciated.  I will correct the code above in the event it helps someone else.

Comment: Np mate, it happens, glad that the problem is solved :)